# idle-python for RHEL 7

Tags: mariadb, python-idle

Python community.  I am looking for a Red Enterprise Linux 7 version of IDLE - Python GUI.  The only version I have found are for Windows and Mac.   I will be using it to test and build an API to tie in with http.

Answer (score 0):

IDLE is in the `python-tools` package.